# Kubernetes NodePort service port change

Tags: kubernetes

Can the Kubernetes NodePort service port change upon service restart or pod crash? How do you ensure that the port of NodePort service remains the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport)

> If you set the **type** field to **NodePort**, the Kubernetes master will allocate a port from a range specified by **--service-node-port-range** flag (default: 30000-32767), and each Node will proxy that port (the same port number on every Node) into your Service. That port will be reported in your **Service**’s **.spec.ports[*].nodePort** field.

Pod crash or restart will not change your NodePort. Re-creating your service will.

You can specify a custom NodePort as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43944385/7568391), this will keep Service's NodePort the same