# How to map nodePort to my own defined port

Tags: kubernetes

I have a service which is accessible on 8081. If I do via docker-compose or swarm without any specific changing on port it's work.

```
 http://$(minikube ip):8081
```

but when i run my app via Kubernetes(minikube) is assign a nodePort in range of 30000-32767.
Then i have to call as follow:

```
http://$(minikube ip):30546
```

which is not acceptable from my service. Is there any way to map randomly given port to my own defined port?
When call second url then i am getting connection refused
I also used

```
kubectl port forward my-service 8081
```

but still no success.

Comment: This may be duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43935502/kubernetes-nodeport-custom-port/57623930#57623930

Comment: You are using wrong command to forward the port. You need to use ```kubectl port-forward svc/my-service 8081:8081```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kubernetes NodePort Custom Port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43935502/kubernetes-nodeport-custom-port)

Answer (score 1):

kubectl port-forward command is incorrect. try below one

```
kubectl port-forward svc/my-service 8081:8081
```

then you should be able to access the service at http//:127.0.0.1:8081

Comment: There is no kubectl port forward. Only able to to kubectl port-forward. are u sure? @P

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not specific to Minikube but applicable to any Kubernetes cluster running inside a docker container.

In order to send a request from the host machine to the Kubernetes pod running in a container, you have to map ports from host machine to all the way to the pod.

Here is how you do it:

1. Publish the NodePort you want to use inside container to the host machine using `--publish` or `-p`.

```sh
# Map port 8080 on host machine to 31080 inside the container
docker run -p 8080:31080 ...
```

2. Use a custom NodePort when creating the service:

```sh
# You need to specify the exposed port as the nodePort value
# Otherwise Kubernetes will generate a random nodePort for you 
kubectl create service nodeport myservice --node-port=31080 --tcp=3000:80
```

The application inside the pod listens to port `80` which is exposed as a service at port `3000`. The traffic received at port 31080 on Kubernetes node will be directed at this service.

The query you send to 8080 on your host machine will follow this path:

```sh
Request -> Host Machine -> Docker Container -> Kubernetes Node -> Service -> Pod
               ↑                   ↑                 ↑              ↑         ↑
          localhost:8080         :31080           :31080          :3000      :80
```

References:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#-em-service-nodeport-em-

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this in a non-cloud environment is by using the `type: NodePort` with the external IPs configuration. I have this API service defined here:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    service: api
  name: api
spec:
  externalIPs:
  - <ip of your node>
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: "http"
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
```

Now when the service is applied it will have a defined external IP:

```
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)        AGE
api          NodePort    10.43.138.4    <specified IP>  80:30685/TCP   41m
```

When you use this service's IP address and port combination, traffic is forwarded to the service's pods based on the service's selector. And now I can access the API outside of my cluster `curl <specified IP>:80` This method works well when you want control over which specific IPs can be used to access your service.